# Imu orieantation data increase by oneself

Tags: ros, imu, navigation

I subscriber imu data and print it from my python script.I move imu sensor fast then stop the move but imu data still increasing by oneself. How can I slove this problem?

````
imu orientation.z:  -0.332
imu orientation.z:  -0.333
imu orientation.z:  -0.308
imu orientation.z:  -0.324
imu orientation.z:  -0.315
imu orientation.z:  -0.422
imu orientation.z:  -0.373
imu orientation.z:  -0.396
imu orientation.z:  -0.344
imu orientation.z:  -0.378
imu orientation.z:  -0.349
imu orientation.z:  -0.367
imu orientation.z:  -0.404
imu orientation.z:  -0.376
imu orientation.z:  -0.35
imu orientation.z:  -0.326
imu orientation.z:  -0.304
imu orientation.z:  -0.39
imu orientation.z:  -0.567
imu orientation.z:  -0.555
imu orientation.z:  -0.65
imu orientation.z:  -0.64
imu orientation.z:  -0.621
imu orientation.z:  -0.621
imu orientation.z:  -0.621
imu orientation.z:  -0.621 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is called drift. IMU's are integrating accelerations from the accelerometers and angular velocity from gyroscopes. However all sensors have noise and when that noise in the signal is not exactly balanced it's called bias. And as you integrate the noisy signals the bias results in drift.

Analog Devices has a decent overview: [The Case of the Misguided Gyro](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-139.html)

The drift rate is one of the primary performance metrics for an IMU. [How Adafruit compares Gyros](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-sensorlab-gyroscope-calibration/comparing-gyroscopes) And [here are a few examples of them evaluating them](https://learn.adafruit.com/comparing-gyroscope-datasheets)

And there are various ways to try to calibrate the bias to reduce it. [Discussion of calibration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445787/what-actually-causes-gyroscope-drift-in-imu)